# Uploading code in Gitorious

Tags: gitorious

I created an account in Gitorious and I want to upload code from my computer, but I don't know how to do it. Searching in internet I realized that I can't watch the menu to upload code from the dashboard.

I created the public SSH Key and I created a project and a repository. How can I upload the code from my computer?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your operating sysstem (consider using Linux). Are you familiar with [git](http://git-scm.com/) on the command line ?

Comment: My operating system is Windows 7, but I know how works Linux, because I worked.

Answer (score 0):

The answer :

1. add new project and new repo on gitorious
2. on your local disc in program directory :

   ```
   git init
   git add .
   git commit -m " name " 
   git remote add origin git@gitorious.org:my-project-name/my-git-repo.git
   git push origin master
   ```

If you will have error :

```
   fatal: remote origin already exists.
```

then :

```
   git remote rm origin
   git remote add origin git@gitorious.org:my-project-name/my-git-repo.git
   git push origin master
```

It is based on :

1. [faq - How do I point my local Git repository at Gitorious?](https://gitorious.org/about/faq)
2. [Creating a new git repository in Gitorious by kosmas](http://www.42.mach7x.com/2010/12/30/creating-a-new-git-repository-in-gitorious/)
3. [Getting started with Git and Gitorious by sagarun](https://arunsag.wordpress.com/2009/07/04/getting-started-with-git-and-gitorious/)